# What is the correct language for talking about cyclocross?

Tags: cyclocross

Just a small one that has me stumped. In a newspaper article where I live in New Zealand there is a picture of guy riding a cyclocross bike with a caption saying that he is mountain biking. I realised I don't know the verb for riding a CX bike, is it simply called cycling or mountain biking?

Comment: As a fellow Kiwi, I am more surprised that the reporter got it that close... You are talking about people who refer to Mountain Climbers using Icepicks (Sharon Stone's character used one in Basic Instinct), I doubt they will grasp the difference between MTB and CX in my lifetime......

Comment: It was an article about a vegan cyclist's picture being used on a McDonald's billboard without permission so you're probably right to be surprised!!

Comment: When I saw this thought "Dutch?" Not quite what you're after though, I think.

Answer (score 3):

"Cycling."
Can't go wrong. No specific verb for "cyclocrossing" that I've ever heard. "Racing" when doing so, which is often when on a cyclocross bike.

Comment: I've also heard (and said) "racing cross"

Answer (score 2):

Use the terminology you like. If enough people agree and use the same terminology, then that will become the correct way to speak about it. When Shakespear needed words to express new ideas, he invented or re-interperted terms from other languages, creating neologisms as needed.

I've heard people say Cross Riding, Cross Racing, Cyclocrossing, Crossing, Riding Cross, Racing Cross, Cross Biking.

Comment: "CX-ing" works well in print, or if you've got some King flair on your bike, you could call it "Chris-Crossing."  Ha...  Shakespeare was also a fan of corny puns, you know.